# /usr/local/bin/pecl: 28: exec: /usr/local/bin/php: not found?

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04, xdebug, pecl

I'm trying to install xdebug with a command:

```
pecl install -f xdebug-2.9.8
```

but this command produces:

```
/usr/local/bin/pecl: 28: exec: /usr/local/bin/php: not found
```

echo $PATH - produces

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked whether `/usr/local/bin/php` exists?

Comment: I just figured out, that it says that there is no php folder in path

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
First find out where is php executable:

```
which php7.2
```

In my case it was:

```
/usr/bin/php7.2
```

Then link it to place, that pecl want it to be:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php7.2 /usr/local/bin/php
```

Comment: This should've been a comment, not an answer